# Java str.split returning empty elements using RegEx

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I want to strip out anything from a string that **isn't** a plus sign, or a minus, or a multiplication sign or a division sign (/).

So i thought I'd use RegEx and negative lookahead.

Given a Java array:

`String[] operandsArray = str.split("(?!\\u002A|\\u002B|\\u002D|\\u002F).")`

And a test string of 55+5, the resulting array `operandsArray` contains:

```
0:""
1:""
2:"+"
```

I'm looking for it to contain just the operands, so:

```
0:"+"
```

and given: 55+6-6*6/6, would return:

```
0:"+"
1:"-"
2:"*"
3:"/"
```

It should also match duplicates as well, so given 5+5+5+5, would return:

```
0:"+"
1:"+"
2:"+"
```

Can anyone help with this, thanks

Comment: It seems you just want to [match and extract](https://ideone.com/NRMDS5) with `[-+/*]` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, using `[-+/*]` will strip out the operands and leave behind anything else, resulting in an array that, say given 55+5, would contain 55 and 5,  I'm looking to do the opposite so that only * would remain

Comment: Remove everything which is not an operator and then split at each char: `str.replaceAll("[^-+/*]","").split("")`

Comment: @WhatTheWhat Did you seem the solution I linked to?

Comment: @user16320675 Hi, the symbol * also does other stuff in regex, so safer to use  unicode instead

Comment: @Eritrean, the issue with `str.replaceAll("[^-+/*]","").split("")` is that it will always return an array with something in it. So given an entry of "dc", the resulting array will have a size of 1 with nothing in it.

Comment: Narrowing it down; `String[] operandsArray = str.split("[^*/+-]+");` only produces one empty value at the element [0] of the array

Comment: *Do not use `split`*,  use *`Matcher#find`* as I showed in my top comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "55+6-6*6/6";
        String[] results = Pattern.compile("[+/*-]").matcher(text)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results)); 
    }
}
```

See [Java proof](https://tio.run/##bY8/a8MwEMVn61McniSHKFM82HTo0LFQmm4hg@oIR6n@IZ0Th5LP7sp2MIX2loP3e@8ddxYXsT4fv4ZBGe8CwjkJvEOleVGTP1rEIIX5FwXZyn4kpNEiRviQEck3yXz3qVUDEQWmdXHqCEYoC3SHQdl2fwAR2sgAT8Fd41yohW35S99Ij8pZkqWabLYDyh7hCfLtdlWuy6LclHm90FQWZOw0xmR5E4gyWN4445WWNN@vNsX6kDNuBDYnGejYxVIY0vBHkC6CEZ6@js73iVRVG1znGYFfw9E9hyBuyzNVZeWV1ZMp290iSsNdh9wnjNrSyR1TbA7Qx1XGaiDZndyH4Qc).

**Results**: `[+, -, *, /]`